# show the following including euclidean norm

Tags: analysis

How do I show that the open set is the same as when we make the definition of an open set in $R^n$ using norm

a.$||.||_1$      b.$||.||_{\infty}$   c.$||.||_2$(Euclidean norm)

So I know that for $V \subset R^n$ , $B_{r}(a)$ = {$ x\in   R^n:||x-a||< \epsilon$} $\subset$ V which is open is the definition of an open set. Bu show the question?

Comment: You have to show that the different norms give rise to the same notion of "openness" (that is, sets that don't contain any of their boundary points). It's usually done by taking an open _ball_ in one norm, and showing that the resulting set is open (although not a ball) when using the two other norms.

Comment: So I just need to show that it is a diamond and a square for the two others right? @Arthur I got a diamond for l1 and a square for $||.||_{\infty}$. What do I do from here?

Comment: You show that in the norm that thinks open balls look like diamonds, squares and circles are open too. And so on for all of them.

Comment: I was thinking again and showing it by shapes gets to complicated. How do I explicitly  show it by using the definition of openness as you claimed in the first comment? @Arthur

Answer (score 1):

I'll show that a set $U\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ that is open in the $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm is open in the other two norms.

First of all, open means that it's the union of open balls: any point $x$ in $U$ has an open ball $B_{1}(x, a) = \{y \mid \|x-y\|_1 < a\}$ for some real number $a > 0$ such that $B \subseteq U$. Thus if we can show that any such $B_1$ can be covered by balls $B_2$ and by balls $B_\infty$, then of course $U$ can be covered by such balls, and therefore $U$ is $\|\cdot \|_2$-open and $\|\cdot \|_\infty$-open as well.

Take a set $B = B_1(x, a)$, the $\|\cdot \|_1$-ball of radius $a$, centered around the point $x \in \Bbb R^2$. $B$ has the shape of a diamond, and the boundary of that diamond is not part of the set.

Take a point $y \in B$. Then that point has a shortest euclidean distance $\epsilon$ to the boundary of $B$. Therefore, the ball $B_2(y, \epsilon)$ is completely contained in $B$. Also, we know that the ball $B_\infty(y , \epsilon/\sqrt2)$ looks like a square, inscribed in the circle that is $B_2(y, \epsilon)$, so that set is also completely contained in $B$.

Since we have concluded that any point $x \in B$ has both a $\|\cdot \|_2$-neighbourhood and a $\|\cdot \|_\infty$-neighourhood that is contained in $B$, we conclude that $B$ is open in both of these norms. Then the second paragraph shows that any $\|\cdot \|_1$-open set is open in the two other norms as well.

These two last paragraphs must also be done for the other two norms, and then you're done.